# How to allow user to send Email without authentication

Tags: android, email

I'm trying to allow user to send me an Email to get some feedbacks.

I have been searching about solutions, some says 'use SMTP' and some people say 'use Javax library'.

In their answers, both require user ID and password.

I wonder if allowing users to send email is even possible since there will be no login in in my app.

Now I'm using Intent.SEND but I would like it to work in OnClick not to open any email app

Please let me know what I can use for my problem, or leave a link in a comment

Appreciate your answer in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use **Intent.ACTION_SENDTO**.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:desiredmailaddress"));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject of email");
startActivity(emailIntent);
```

This should work fine.

Comment: Oh I did't mention one more thing, I would like it to work in button OnClick Listener.

Comment: Isn't it going to open email app anyway? I want them to be able to send mail in my app without opening any Email app

Comment: I don't know whether that's possible or not. But sending sms without any other app is possible.

Comment: Another way can be... by using Firebase.

Comment: It's asking developer a question, so it should be Email Intent since users abroad can't send me sms